# Can't load DLL with remote codeBase: Downloaded file was not cached. The web server may be configured to expire content immediately

Tags: c#

I'm trying to load a DLL remotely, it has strong sign enabled, and works with `file:///` path.

However, when I try to load it remotely via a valid https url,

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="yyy" publicKeyToken="yyy" culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase version="yyy" href="https://yyy.com/yyy.dll" />
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
      <etwEnable enabled="false" />
      <appDomainManagerAssembly value="yyy, Version=yyy, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yyy" />
      <appDomainManagerType value="yyy" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It fails with

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'yyy, Version=yyy, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yyy' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I looked into the binding logs,

```
WRN: Application configuration file binding redirects disallowed.
LOG: Post-policy reference: yyy, Version=yyy, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yyy
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL https://yyyx/yyyx.dll.
ERR: Downloaded file was not cached. The web server may be configured to expire content immediately.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

What does `Downloaded file was not cached. The web server may be configured to expire content immediately.` mean here? The dll is hosted on a apache server, it returns these headers

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2024 14:29:57 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Last-Modified: yyyxx
< ETag: "yyy-yyyx"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: yyy
< Cache-Control: max-age=84600, public
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, from apache logs the DLL is successfully downloaded. So is there any specific requirements on the headers?